# A regular expression to match a string delimited by characters that does not contain the delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for the regex expression for a `string` matching a `string` starting with a `;` and ending with a `:`, that contain neither `;` nor `:`

For example `";zreazer:"` should match but `";raz:er:"` or `";er;:"` should not.

Any idea? :) Thanks in advance, I tried some with `^` and `?!` symbols but it didn't work out very well.

Comment: [`;[^;:]*?:`](https://regex101.com/r/SMpnMx/1) something like that?

Comment: It might be that, but why both "*" and "?" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Added an answer for posterity. Feel free to mark accepted.

Comment: Actually, the greedy vs non-greedy thing is irrelevant here, because you're matching right to the end of the string.  I'd do this without the `?`, just for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for

```
;[^;:]*:
```

`;` and `:` are the delimiters. `[^;:]` will match any string in between the delimiters that does not include these delimiters.

Here's a [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SMpnMx/3) demo. I've added double quotes to the expression to make it obvious.

---

A good reference for regular expressions can be found here in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: What exactly does non-greedy match mean?

Comment: @Mike This link will answer your question much better than I can in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Comment: What is the point of making it non-greedy here? You are looking for string which starts with `;`, ends with `:` and has no `;:` between.

Comment: @Pshemo Point. Edited :]